# C++ Linux documentation: some std lib items seem to be missing

Tags: c++, linux, manpage

I am trying to use Linux tools as my reference at the moment, since they are faster.  I have gotten things like `man std::vector` to work by installing `libstdc++-6...`.

However, I am missing things like `std::accumulate`.  Where can i find the man pages for the algorithms header?

Comment: I recommend [this reference site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) instead.

Comment: Note that while reference sites can document Standard C++, implementation-defined behavior must of course be defined by the implementation documentation, so you ca't fall back to generic documentation. However, there's simply no implementation-defined behavior in `std::accumulate`.

Comment: If you really need doc. to be local, you will find interesting references in the [C++ tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info), and specifically drafts of the standards ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)). But the cpprefrence site recommended by Some programmer dude is a very nice source of information (IMHO the best).